# struct not holding new values

Tags: c, struct, stack, pass-by-reference, pass-by-value

I am making a stack using struct in C, I ran this in the gcc debugger and noticed that in the push() function after providing the value of 'ele' the arr[0] is set to 'ele' and 'top' becomes 0.

But as soon as I exit out of push() the arr[0] is going back again to garbage value and top is becoming -1. Why is that happening. How to make arr[0] hold its value I am providing and top to remain 0.

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define MAX 10

typedef struct
{
    int top;
    int arr[MAX];
    int ele;

} STACK;

void push(STACK st)
{
    printf("Enter element ");
    scanf("%d", &st.ele);
    if (!isFull(st))
    {
        st.arr[++(st.top)] = st.ele;
    }
    else
    {
        printf("****Stack is full****\n");
    }
}


int main()
{
    STACK st;
    st.top = -1;
    int choice;
    for (;;)
    {
        printf("Stack elements : \n");
        printf("Enter choice \n");
        printf("1.Push\n2.Pop\n3.Display\n4.Peek Top element\n");
        scanf("%d", &choice);
        switch (choice)
        {
        case 1:
            push(st);
            break;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Because `push()` only changes the *copy* of the struct it was passed, which is thrown away on function exit.

Comment: @WeatherVane I am new to this, can you tell how to make it hold the copy?

Comment: Two options: make the argument a **pointer** to the struct (with appropriate changes), or `return` the struct and assign to the caller's variable, for example `st = push(st);`. Prefer the first, especially when the struct is large.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For starters the data member `ele` is redundant in this structure definition

```
typedef struct
{
    int top;
    int arr[MAX];
    int ele;

} STACK;
```

Define the structure like

```
typedef struct
{
    int top;
    int arr[MAX];
} STACK;
```

The function push accepts its argument by value

```
void push(STACK st)
```

It means that the function deals with a copy of the original argument. Changing the copy does not influence on the original object used as an argument.

You need to pass the original object of the structure type by reference.

In C passing by reference means passing an object indirectly through a pointer to it.

Moreover within the function you need at first to check whether the stack is full before entering a new value.

So the function should be declared and defined the following way

```
void push( STACK *st )
{
    if (!isFull( st))
    {
        printf("Enter element ");
    
        int ele;

        if ( scanf("%d", &ele ) == 1 )
        {
            st->arr[++(st->top)] = ele;
        }
        else
        {
            puts( "****i/o error occured****" );
        }
    }
    else
    {
        printf("****Stack is full****\n");
    }
}
```

Within the function you need to wirte

```
st->arr[++(st->top)] = ele;
```

And the function is called like

```
push( &st );
```

Pay attention to that the function isFull in turn should be declared like

```
int isFull( const STACK *st );
```

Answer (score 1):

```
void push(STACK st)
```

Needs to be

```
void push(STACK *st)
```

What's happening is that you're modifying a copy of st not the st you passed into push.

Answer (score 1):

The `push()` function is receiving the copy of `st` and making changes in that copy. Note that parameter `STACK st` is local to `push()`. Any changes you make in its value will not be available outside of `push()`.

Pass the address of `STACK` structure in `push()`, like this

```
push(&st);
```

Make the relevant changes in `push()` -

Change the prototype of `push()` [parameter type should be `STACK` pointer]:

```
void push(STACK * st)
```

The other changes in `push()` will be:

```
void push(STACK * st) {
    ....
    scanf("%d", &(st->ele));
    ....
    ....
    st->arr[++(st->top)] = st->ele;
    ....
    ....
}
```

Also, you have to make relevant changes in `isFull()` function, which is called from `push()`. It's good idea to make changes `isFull()` function to receive `STACK` pointer type argument.